# Pre-trained convolutional neural networks for medical images analysis

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I know about pre-trained models, which was trained on ImageNet dataset. Are exists other pre-trained models, which was trained on other datasets such as medical images or at least images which contain structure, patterns etc.?

**UPD**: Under the structure, I understand any patterns, as is the case with cells or tissues

Answer (score 0):

ImageNet does contain structure -- the structure of "natural images" (i.e. images of the real world.) Often models are pre-trained on ImageNet for a downstream medical image analysis application, e.g. [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41551-018-0324-9?WT.feed_name=subjects_cardiovascular-diseases). You can pre-train on a huge data set of natural images (ImageNet, CIFAR etc) and then fine tune on a smaller medical image data set.